# MySQL: Problems counting rows

Tags: mysql, count

Is this supposed to count the appearances of each link_id on the table?

```
SELECT link_id, count(*) FROM table group by link_id
```

I think it should, but if I just execute

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

I get different results. For example, for link 7 I get a count of 40 in the first query, but using 'select *' i see that there are only 4 rows of link 7... What's going on?

Comment: Without seeing your data, it's hard to answer. The first query will give you a table of `link_id`s and the number of times each appears in the table.

Comment: Maybe the tool you use to show the individual rows is not showing you all of them, and simply getting the first n rows back ?

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that's the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is supposed to do that,

Surely it would be easier to do a

```
SELECT DISTINCT count(link_id) FROM table
```

This would give you a single row containing the amount of link_id's

Alternatively

```
SELECT link_id,count(*) FROM table GROUP BY link_id's
```

Returns multiple rows containing the count of each

With regard to the original question you mention there are multiple rows per id, are you doing a join any where?

---

> I get different results. For example, for link 7 I get a count of 40 in the first query, but using 'select *' i see that there are only 4 rows of link 7... What's going on?

Are you sure phpMyAdmin or similar isn't limiting the amount of rows you are seeing?